# Unable to display an image from database in asp.net view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I don't know why, but I am not able to display an image from my database in my view. It appears in the right resolution for the image, but it's basically transperant. I am not sure if something in the way I save the image is wrong(shouldn't be) or if it's something with displayin it. I am sorry if my question is too basic, but I am stuck on this more than I have to be:(

here is a screenshot of the problem : [image]

attr value : 
   src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAADhCAYAAAByfIirAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAANL5JREFUeNrsnQl8VNXZ/8/MZJIJ2UMWIAkJCWFLwhpWAQEBKasoBkUUEBBpq7Xaoi34V2yp/PU="

Here'how my model looks :

```
    public int CompId { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase UploadImage { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string ImageBase64 => System.Convert.ToBase64String(ImageData);
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyAddress { get; set; }
```

Action method :

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CompId,ImageData,CompanyName,CompanyAddress,CompanyCountry,CompanyCity,CompanyPostalCode,CompanyPhoneNumber,EmailCA")] Company company, HttpPostedFileBase UploadImage)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                byte[] buf = new byte[UploadImage.ContentLength];
                UploadImage.InputStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                company.ImageData = buf;

                db.Companies.Add(company);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(company);
        }
```

And the view :

```
 @model eksp.Models.Company

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Company</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImageData)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,@Model.ImageBase64" />
        </dd>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Examine the resulting HTML page source: do you see what is expected in that img src attribute value?

Comment: Also, put a breakpoint in cshtml and check `@Model.ImageData` array. Do you have some data there?

Comment: @uncoder . I just added this value in the question.

Comment: @Alexei , yes there is a value. I can see it in the DB

Comment: @RobertRoss, try my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess what the value you have shown is:

> src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAADhCAYAAAByfIirAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAANL5JREFUeNrsnQl8VNXZ/8/MZJIJ2UMWIAkJCWFLwhpWAQEBKasoBkUUEBBpq7Xaoi34V2yp/PU="

Surprise: 300x225 empty PNG image (with a transparent background):

[image]

So make sure that you put some real images in your database if you expect to see them rendered in the browser. Otherwise all you will get in the browser is a 300x225 pixels emptiness (which is exactly what we are seeing from your screenshot).

This being said, your code is fine, it's the data you are working with that is making you think that there's a problem.

Comment: I will try to reupload the image. p.s здрасти :д

Comment: Just make sure to upload some more *visible* image :-)

Comment: Yes, thanks for this. It worked now. I don't know how this happend :D